# using Python list to set conditional pandas statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a calculation that I need to aggregate, but it will not work with GROUPBY in PANDAs. So, I'm stuck with iterating over the groups manually. The groups are defined by 2 fields of 'object' type values, which are essentially the categories.

I think an elegant solution may be to create 2 lists from the unique values in the 2 independent columns with categorical values.
Then create a 'for' loop, and using string values or something, iterate through my PANDAs conditional statement to create a DataFrame; which then eventually does my aggregate calc. This occurs over and over, with only the dataframe with aggregate calculation being kept in memory, with some append of a counter value like '1' to the end of 'df_'. In order to not overwrite each time through the loop. Here is my psuedo code.

```
cats1=['blue','yellow','pink']
cats2=['dog','horse','cow','sheep']
lengths=list(itertools.product(cats1,cats2))

for x,y,z in zip(cats1,cats2,lengths):
    df = main_df[ (main_df['col2']==x) & (main_df['col3']==y) ]
    df['aggcalc'] = df['col1'].agg.mean()
    locals()['df_{0}'.format(z)] = df
```

The last line will hopefully create the persistent dataframe based on the number of combinations of 'cats1' and 'cats2'. ie, "df_1", "df_2", etc... Then the "df" in the 1st 2 lines just gets overwritten each time in the 'for' loop. Is this correct thinking?

EDIT..............
Here is a simpler way to look at it.
I want to loop through all possible combinations from 2 independent, varying-length lists. Additionally, I want in each loop to have a 'counter', 'z'. This is the current way to write this and subsequent output:

```
 for x,y in list(itertools.product(cats1,cats2)):
     print x,y    


   blue dog
   blue horse
   blue cow
   blue sheep
   yellow dog
   yellow horse
   yellow cow
   yellow sheep
   pink dog
   pink horse
   pink cow
   pink sheep
```

How do I add to this output a 'z' variable which will make the output look like

```
   blue dog 0
   blue horse 1
   blue cow 2
   blue sheep 3
   yellow dog 4
```

...etc

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I am sure if you post a sample dataset and show your desired output, we can suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your edit is to just use `enumerate`:

```
for z, (x, y) in enumerate(itertools.product(cats1, cats2)):
    print x, y, z

blue dog 0
blue horse 1
blue cow 2
blue sheep 3
yellow dog 4
yellow horse 5
yellow cow 6
yellow sheep 7
pink dog 8
pink horse 9
pink cow 10
pink sheep 11
```

I strongly suspect that you're missing a simpler solution with `groupby` though, and so I'd recommend posting a new question with dummy data and details of what aggregation you're trying to perform.

Comment: Agreed. I use groupby whenever possible. Yet the algorithm in the module I'm using doesn't function with groupby because of a bug.